# marginfix and letter class

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginpar, letters

One of the things I like about the `letter` class is that it vertically centers 1 page letters on the page. I recently discovered the [`marginfix`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/marginfix) package, but it seems to prevent the centering behavior.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{}
    I like to use marginals for editing notes.\marginpar{FIX THIS}

        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The letter is not vertically centered when [`marginfix`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/marginfix) is used.

I can get the centering back with `\def\MFX@attachmargin{}`, but I am pretty sure that defeats the purpose of loading [`marginfix`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/marginfix). Is there a way to make [`marginfix`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/marginfix) and vertical centering compatible?

Comment: Could you give an example, how you are using it? It is hard for me to imagine a letter with marginals.

Comment: @Andy I use marginals for "todo" notes while editing. I know I could, possibly should, use something like the `todo` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the code, `marginfix` messes with the output routine. That means that 'all bets are off', so I'd say the answer here is 'no'.